# Using “the” with names of functions, variables, constants in computer literature

Tags: definite-article

When I write computer-related text and want to refer to something (a variable, a function, etc.) that has a unique name, should I add “the” before the name?  For example: “Here I call the `printf` function” vs “Here I call `printf` function.” Logically it seems that the name is a sufficient determiner, but at the same time I see that many people use “the” here.

Comment: Typical usage is to use the determiner or elide both the article and the word *function*: "I call the `printf` function" or simply "I call `printf`".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Function*** is a count noun, and it typically appears with a determiner of some sort:

> I called **a function**.
>   I called **this function**.
>   I called **the function**.
>   I called **two functions**.

Lots of determiners work, as you can see above.

You can add the name of the function as an attributive modifier:

> I called **the `printf` function**.

And in that case, you've made it specific, so ***the*** is probably the appropriate determiner (unless you're in an unusual situation where you have more than one `printf` function to discuss).

But ***function*** needs a determiner, so these are ungrammatical:

> *I called **function**.　　　　 　*(ungrammatical)*
>   *I called **`printf` function**.　*(ungrammatical)*

By itself, `printf` doesn't need a determiner.  It's a proper noun:

> I called `printf`.

This is fine too, and I think it's probably more common in speech, but I don't have a corpus to check, so that's really just a guess.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks an utterance as ungrammatical.

Comment: I like your aside about the possibility of having multiple *printf* functions available. Covers all the bases!

Comment: It should probably be noted that even though `printf` is a proper noun, the rules about capitalization of proper nouns generally don't apply. Particularly if you're discussing a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Great answer, grammatically, but from the point of computer programming you should always include parenthesis when talking about functions -- since no function is complete without them!  So even more correct than anything above is "I called the printf() function."

Comment: ...oh and "I called printf()" would be a more informal use.  But you could say something like "This clearly calls for printf()."

Comment: To be really proper, should one include an ellipsis between the parentheses to indicate that required argument(s) must be specified? E.g., `printf(...)`

Comment: I disagree with "you should always include parenthesis when talking about functions". You're talking about the function itself, not the invocation of it. In fact, `printf()` isn't even valid code, so what value are the parentheses adding? The name of the function is `printf`. Its name is not `printf()`.

Comment: ...And not every language needs/allows parenthesis to call a function.

Answer (score 7):

The preferred and most common usage is simply "Here I call `printf`."  A construct like "Here I call the `printf` function" is needlessly verbose.  The exception is when the word `printf` would appear at the beginning of a sentence.  It cannot be capitalized because its case is part of its correct spelling, and leaving it uncapitalized is typographically awkward.

Comment: Or possibly if you're writing for a non-programmer audience, where you need to make it clear that printf IS a function.

Comment: @jamesqf: In that case, I believe the phrasing "Here I call the function *printf*." would best achieve clarity, conciseness, and description.

Answer (score 1):

'the' should be used with printf because we are talking about a particular command. We should use 'the' when pointing to a specific thing.

> Here I call **the printf** function

is correct usage.